# Could anyone make a code to show how to prepare testing code

Tags: java, string, testing

Could anyone make in Java test code for class below?
I would like to see how to prepare this. Can we prepare random ?

```
public class SortString {

  public static void selectionSort(String[] s) {
    for (int toInd = s.length-1; toInd > 0; toInd--) {
      int indMax = 0;

      for (int k = 1; k <= toInd; k++) {
        if (s[indMax].compareTo(s[k]) < 0) {
          indMax = k;
        }
      }

      String temp = s[toInd];
      s[toInd] = s[indMax];
      s[indMax] = temp;
    }
  }


  public static void show(String[] s) {
    System.out.print('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(" " + s[i]);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s =  {"A", "Z", "C", "B", "1", "3", "2", "A", "C" };

    show(s);
    selectionSort(s);
    show(s);
  }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you want to unit test your code. Then a series of fixed arrays would be better than a randomly generated one in my opinion. That way your test would be repeatable, and you would not need to write code that would validate if that randomly generated array is sorted correctly. You might want to look into JUnit to build your unit test.

Comment: What are you trying to test?  'Test code' is not really a generic thing, but needs to be geared towards something.  Also, what framework are you trying to use?  [JML?](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML/) [JUnit?](http://www.junit.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JUnit test testing the case you print in main():

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class SortStringTest {
    @Test
    public void testSelectionSort() {
        String[] s = {"A", "Z", "C", "B", "1", "3", "2", "A", "C"};
        String[] expected = { "1", "2", "3", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "Z"};

        SortString.selectionSort(s);
        assertArrayEquals(expected, s);
    }
}
```

You'd probably want to come up with some more cases to try to test all aspects of your implementation.